# I am trying to filter a table and out of those filers take off some names using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table and I would like to automatically make a filter and take some names that I do not need for the moment. Example

NAME age
luis 11
carlos 12 
jose 13

I would like to me a filter of that table and take off the name carlos and jose. here is the code that I have but its not working. I get error Application fefined or obeject defined error

```
'Naming a range
Sub sbCreatTable()
'Create Table in Excel VBA
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A5:g35"), , xlYes).Name = "myTable1"
Call sbFilterTable

End Sub
Sub sbFilterTable()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("0000_UK").ListObjects("myTable1").Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="france"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbCreateTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("F1:G4"), , xlYes) '"A5:g35"), , xlYes)
tbl.Name = "myTable1"
sbFilterTable tbl

End Sub

Sub sbFilterTable(tbl As ListObject)

tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Luis"

End Sub
```

Assuming your table is on the `ActiveSheet`. If your table is always on `Sheets("0000_UK")`, then just use `Set ws = Sheets("0000_UK")`.

**Note:** I changed "sbCreatTable()" to "sbCreateTable()" because it was bugging me :)

Comment: It works perfectly! But the thing is that I have a list of names I want to take out so basically, I want to say " from this list here  are the names I do not want to see on the table : luis, carlos so the table should show me only Jose @theengineer

Comment: Do you need that list to be dynamic? If so, are you asking the user to choose the names? And do you need the filtering to be done in VBA?

Comment: That would be nice but I can just go and change the names in the code @theengineer

Comment: Oh okay, so it sounds like you are satisfied with this code at this point. If you need anything further, please let me know.

Comment: what do I do if I want to add another name more than luis

Comment: Just change `tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Luis"` to `tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Luis", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Jose"`.